# How do I implement my react component on my site?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

New to react and was following a tutorial creating this component. (https://github.com/owenchak/react-weather). I'm using gulp to test everything locally. How do I use my component in an actual website I'm trying to create? I instructed gulp to create a style.css (containing all the sass files), main.js containing the interpretable jsx and index.html that contains all these files.

Comment: Have you seen [this in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/web-components.html)? Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Hmmm not quite. I was referring to a React component, not a web component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this before. If you take the bundled js (and) and css and attach it to your html and you've created an element where react will be rendered (e,g `<div id="app"></div>`) it will work.